# Interpret binary value as an integer

Tags: erlang

I have a function that seems to expect an integer, but I have a binary value.  Can I tell Erlang to interpret the binary as an integer?

How could I get this code to work (in the REPL)?

```
Binary = <<"hello world">>.
Integer = binary_to_integer(Binary).  % fix me
Increment = Integer + 1.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a bit syntax expression to extract integers from binaries:

```
2> Binary = <<"hello world">>.
<<"hello world">>
3> Bits = bit_size(Binary).
88
4> <<Integer:Bits>> = Binary.
<<"hello world">>
5> Integer.
126207244316550804821666916
6> Increment = Integer + 1.
126207244316550804821666917
7> <<Increment:Bits>>.
<<"hello worle">>
```

Read the full description and some examples in [the reference manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id78513).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shorter version:

```
> crypto:bytes_to_integer(<<"hello world">>).
126207244316550804821666916
```

Comment: My Erlang (r15b01) has a crypto module, but it doesn't contain bytes_to_integer/1.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot It's in R16B01:)